# PHP5-FPM secondary pool not starting (111: Connection refused)

Tags: php

I have the default [www] pool up and running with no problems. I wanted to run another one to separate the process for another site.

I have the following conf:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/site2.conf

[site2]

user = site2
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-site2.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

/etc/nginx/sites/site.net

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-site2.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The socket/user do exist in /var/run and the ownership/permissions are all OK however when I run the php5-server only the default www is starting and I get

```
2016/04/26 16:30:24 [error] 27908#0: *35895 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-site2.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with php5-fpm process, for some reason the master process was terminated so any command would fail (it wasn't restarting at all).
So I fixed with:

```
sudo pkill php5-fpm; sudo service php5-fpm start
```

This could be related [Ubuntu php5-fpm throws unknown instance on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998526/ubuntu-php5-fpm-throws-unknown-instance-on-reload)